# How to default `ps aux` to `ww`?

Tags: bash, terminal, ps, gnome-terminal

When you use a default Terminal + Bash from Ubuntu 20.02.1 LTS with Gnome 3.36.3, `ps aux` seems to automatically include the unlimited width.

But when I use `powershell` or `xterm`, the `ps aux` is truncated by default, and you have to manually specify `auxww` to get the full output.

Which makes me think that this is controlled by some sort of environment variable.

What makes `ps aux` automatically default to `ww` so that the output is not truncated? In my case, I never want the `ps aux` output to be truncated.

Answer (score 3):

Use an alias:

```
alias ps="ps ww"
```

You can put that line in your `~/.bashrc` startup file and it will be used irrespective of the terminal properties.

On some systems aliases are put in a `~/.alias` file instead.  That file is then `source`d in `~/.bashrc`, for example with a line like

```
test -s ~/.alias && . ~/.alias || true
```

in `~/.bashrc`.  The difference is merely cosmetic, though and most relevant if you have a long `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

If the environment variable $COLUMNS was set and exported, 'ps aux' is truncated.
In order to prevent truncation, unset COLUMNS.

Comment: I do not have `${COLUMNS}` set and the output is still truncated. There seems to be some auto-detection of terminal width taking place.